# The synchronous form of require throws errors when resolving a circular dependency, unless I rename require

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, circular-dependency

I have a strange behaviour in require, that I dont know how to avoid (or maybe I have my basics wrong?).

Consider the following code:

```
define (require) ->

  potoo = require "potoo"
  service = require "communication.data"

  downloadIfNeeded = ->
    # ...
    service.download()

  new potoo.App
    pageContainer: potoo.UI.NGStylePage
    userRequired:  true
    stdRoute:      "overview"
    onLogin:       downloadIfNeeded
```

This is not going to work, because 'communication.data' itself requires 'app' (the code shown). so we obviously have a circular dependency. That fails with a 'Uncaught Error: Module name "app" has not been loaded yet for context: _'

Since the downloadIfNeeded function doesn't get called until after the user actually clicks something, I figured, that something like the following should work:

```
define (require) ->

  potoo = require "potoo"

  downloadIfNeeded = ->
    service = require "communication.data"
    service.download()

  ...
```

But that actually throws the same error as above. To make it work, i have to use a little hack. I alias the require function with some other name:

```
define (require) ->

  potoo = require "potoo"
  reqs = require

  downloadIfNeeded = ->
    service = reqs "communication.data"
    service.download()

  ...
```

Is this the best way to do so? Or would you recommend the CommonJS Style (module.export) that is also supported by requirejs.

Comment: I've removed the sidenote you had at the bottom of your question. It was in effect a *different* question (answering your circularity problem does not entail answering this second question). Moreover, what you were asking is not a good fit for SO since it is opinion-based or too broad. ("Recommend it" for what purpose specifically? It may be better than RequireJS in some respects but not in others. Etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a test here and was able to find a solution. What you have is equivalent to this JavaScript:

```
define(function (require) {
```

This is enough to be able to use the (fake) synchronous form of `require`. However, RequireJS will give you the error you got when you try to use a synchronous `require` and you have circular dependencies. What you need is this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
```

This is so that your module uses `exports` to export its values and consequently RequireJS has an object that can be updated when the module has finished initialized.